# Is there a name for defining recursive functions as an infinite list of input/output pairs?

Tags: algorithms, computability, programming-languages, recurrence-relation

Recursive functions are usually defined by directly calling a function inside its own body.

```
Nat = Z | S Nat
double Z = Z
double (S x) = S (S (double x)))
```

What if, instead of defining them this way, we just enumerated two recursive datatypes and zipped them?

To be more descriptive, mind the following functions/types:

```
enum Nat = [Z, S Z, S S Z, S S S Z ...]
elem (S S S Z) (enum Nat) = 3
[4,5,6] !! 1 = 5
zip [1,2,3] [4,5,6] = [(1,4), (2,5), (3,6)]
# a b = \x -> (zip (enum a) (enum b)) !! (elem x (enum a))
```

That is, `enum` enumerates elements of a recursive datatype, `elem`, `!!` and `zip` are just as defined by Haskel. Now, using #, there is an interesting way to define some recursive functions.

```
Even = Z | S (S Even)
double = Nat # Even
```

This makes `double` equivalent to:

```
double x = [(0,0),(1,2),(2,4),(3,6)...] !! x
```

In other words, instead of defining the function recursively, we just created an infinite list with the input/output pairs of that function, by zipping two recursive datatypes together. I never heard of this approach being used, so my question is: this there a name for this? Any relevant papers? What kinds of functions can be defined this way?

Answer (score 1):

Well it's the "set-theoritic" perspective of a function where a function
from `A` onto `B` is really just the a subset of `A x B` where each `a` in `A` appears only once.

The problem is that some types are uncountable so enumerating them in this manner isn't possible; for some types a finite member may not be at a finite index.

Consider for example, how you would do this for `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

For a function $f\colon D \to R$, the set $\{(x,f(x)) : x \in D\} \subseteq D \times R$ is known as the *graph* of the function. We can think of the graph as a sequence (ordered arbitrarily), and then we can say that the graph is *r.e.* if it can be recursively enumerated in some order. Assuming the function is total (and domain and range are both the natural numbers), the graph of a function is r.e. iff the function is computable.

Comment: What is `r.e.`?

Comment: Recursively enumerable.